# Parametros banco Firebase

Tags: firebase, nosql, flutter

O flutter possui para comunicação com o firebase o arquivo google-services.json, teria alguma forma de enviar parâmetros com a key de um outro banco firebase e projectid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer o que você quer, mas de qualquer forma você teria que ter um arquivo .json default.
Para conectar a outra base de dados você teria que criar uma outra instância do `FirebaseApp` e configurá-la como deseja:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
       .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Requirido para o Analytics.
       .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Requirido para o Auth.
       .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
       .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secundaria");
```

E para acessar essa nova instância basta você especificar a mesma no momento de declarar sua conexão

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secundaria");
FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```

Normalmente não precisamos configurar nada manualmente pois o provider do firebase já faz tudo por nós, buscando os dados no arquivo de configuração google-services.json.
No caso então você teria a conexão default, que vem do arquivo de configuração, e para conectar-se a outras bases você faria a conexão manualmente em tempo de execução dinamicamente.

Fonte: [The Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Eu não estou com acesso ao Flutter agora e não cheguei a testar esse método, mas parece ser de certa forma simples.

Existe esta outra [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533409/flutter-multiple-firebase-projects-in-one-app-but-showing-incorrect-data) no SO em inglês que pode te ajudar em algo também

*Esta é uma resposta que formulei para [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406058/usar-mais-de-um-banco-firebase-em-um-app-criado-no-flutter/406084#406084) mas não houve retorno do usuário e como sua pergunta é bem similar a dele, acredito que sirva para você...*

Comment: opa obrigado ja deu uma luz com essa resposta já consigo fazer uns teste.